# Using characteristic functions to show trigonometric equalty

Tags: probability, trigonometry, characteristic-functions

How would I show the following using characteristic functions.

$$\frac{\sin(t)}t=\frac{\sin(t/2)}{t/2}\cos(t/2)$$

and

$$\frac{\sin(t)}t=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(\frac{t}{2^k})$$

Comment: Do you know Euler's formula?

Comment: $sint=\frac{e^{it}-e^{-it}}{2i}$?

Comment: yes, but I didn't read the bit about the characteristic functions, so the proof using Euler's formule isn't the one you'll want

Comment: Take the Fourier transform of both sides. The LHS is characteristic function of an interval. The RHS is convolution of sums of Dirac Deltas, interpret them as sum of independent coin flips, you can argue they converge to the uniform distribution.

Comment: what do mean by characteristic function of an interval?

Comment: @Sav the function that is one on that interval and zero off of it.

Comment: If you're using provablistic language, then I'm talking about the indicator of that interval. In which case the LHS is the characteristic function of the uniform distribution on that interval...

Comment: yes i understand now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try to recursively evaluate the equality,

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\sin t}{t} &=& \color{blue}{\frac{\sin(t/2)}{(t/2)}}\cos(t/2)  \\
&=& \color{blue}{\frac{\sin(t/4)}{(t/4)}\cos(t/4)}\cos(t/2) = \frac{\sin(t/2^2)}{t/2^2}\cos(t/2)\cos(t/2^2) = \frac{\sin(t/2^2)}{t/2^2}\prod_{k=1}^2\cos \left(\frac{t}{2^k}\right) \\
&\vdots&  \\
&=& \frac{\sin (t/2^n)}{t/2^n}\prod_{k=1}^n\cos \left(\frac{t}{2^k}\right) \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

Now take the limit $n \to \infty$, in this case $t/2^n\to 0$ and

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sin (t/2^n)}{t/2^n} = \lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin u}{u} = 1 \tag{2}
$$

Evaluating that in (1) you get

$$
\frac{\sin t}{t} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty\cos \left(\frac{t}{2^k}\right)
$$

Comment: neat proof but im trying to use characteristic functions to show it

Comment: @Sav I see, will delete it in a bit, wouldn't want to contribute to the clutter